Docker container timeouts in bitbucket pipeline
I am trying to create a bitbucket pipeline that uses both docker-compose and semgrep.
I have been unable to get docker running on any image that has semgrep.
My tool that uses semgrep has a container, so I have been attempting a full container solution, however the container seems to timeout and crash after 1:30 min of running.
How can I stop this container task from crashing?
https://bitbucket.org/alex-nightvison/java-test/src/main/bitbucket-pipelines.yml
https://bitbucket.org/alex-nightvison/java-test/pipelines/results/24
Error:
docker run -v $(pwd):/mnt --env "NIGHTVISION_TOKEN=$NIGHTVISION_TOKEN" --add-host=localhost:172.17.0.1 alexnightvision/nightvision-cli nightvision scan -t javaspringvulny-api -a javaspringvulny-api --auth javaspringvulny-api
1m 39s
+ docker run -v $(pwd):/mnt --env "NIGHTVISION_TOKEN=$NIGHTVISION_TOKEN" --add-host=localhost:172.17.0.1 alexnightvision/nightvision-cli nightvision scan -t javaspringvulny-api -a javaspringvulny-api --auth javaspringvulny-api
[2024-04-15 15:30:51] INFO Launching NightVision CLI
[2024-04-15 15:30:53] INFO Starting an OpenAPI Scan
[2024-04-15 15:30:55] INFO Assigned relay ID relayId=NV0RLY01HVH63YPHW3MZ1H4WYZTR2RJM
46950926-7c99-497f-ad68-849495288607
[2024-04-15 15:30:56] INFO Scan initiated 
[2024-04-15 15:30:56] INFO Scan Details:
  info=
  │ Login Status: PENDING
  │ Status: RUNNING
  │ Progress: 0.00%
[2024-04-15 15:31:01] INFO Scanning in progress
[2024-04-15 15:31:06] INFO Scanning in progress
[2024-04-15 15:31:11] INFO Scanning in progress
[2024-04-15 15:31:17] INFO Scanning in progress
[2024-04-15 15:31:22] INFO Scanning in progress
[2024-04-15 15:31:27] INFO Scanning in progress
[2024-04-15 15:31:32] INFO Scanning in progress
[2024-04-15 15:31:38] INFO Scanning in progress
[2024-04-15 15:31:43] INFO Scanning in progress
[2024-04-15 15:31:48] INFO Scanning in progress
[2024-04-15 15:31:53] INFO Scanning in progress
[2024-04-15 15:31:59] INFO Scanning in progress
[2024-04-15 15:32:04] INFO Scanning in progress
[2024-04-15 15:32:09] INFO Scanning in progress
[2024-04-15 15:32:15] INFO Scanning in progress
[2024-04-15 15:32:20] INFO Scanning in progress
[2024-04-15 15:32:29] INFO Scanning in progress
time="2024-04-15T15:32:30Z" level=error msg="error waiting for container: unexpected EOF"


Please paste your yml here for historical purposes
